# highchart tooltip not follow mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I faced a problem with highchart, when I change the mouse the tooltip not change correctly to the selected point,

if anyone have advice it will be great Thanks here is my code

```js
document.body.style.zoom=0.7;
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    width: 300
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Width is set to 300px'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: What is not working correctly ? you mean the data shown doesn't correspand its  categorie ?

Comment: when i move the mouse to a point , the tooltip it show info for another point not the point that i selected

Comment: but here as shown in the snippet every think works fine

Comment: Thanks @BooBerr'ita  the problem was with a javascript code , it works now Thank you

Comment: Why would you need the zoom property changed to 0.7?

Comment: this is just a test code my page is full with things , that why i use  zoom out to see all of details without scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the discussion about this problem on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1753. To workaround, you can correct **chartX** and **chartY** properties in wrap of `normalize` method:

```
document.body.style.zoom = 0.7;

(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'normalize', function(proceed, e) {
        var e = proceed.call(this, e),
            zoom;

        zoom = Number(document.body.style.zoom);
        e.chartX /= zoom;
        e.chartY /= zoom;

        return e;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dnzqum5j/

Comment: Amazing  , now i dont need to delete the zoom line ,you solve my problem Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I find the problem is `document.body.style.zoom=0.7;`

when i remove it , the chart works great